# "Type Coercion failed" when passing String to function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I read txt file like this:

```
private function ReadFile():void
    {
        var loadedPage:String;
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file.txt");
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.load(url);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
        function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            loadedPage = loader.data;
            //if i trace loadedPage here it works great
            reader(loadedPage);
        }
    }
```

reader class is in separate file, it looks like:

```
public class reader
{
    var pageContent:String;

    public function reader(loadedPage:String):void
    {
        pageContent = loadedPage;
        read();
    }

    private function read():void
    {
        trace(pageContent);
    }
}
```

But there I get an error:

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

This is what file.txt contains at first line.

Why do I get this error? I do not try to convert, I just want to pass Sting to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that error because your are trying to [cast](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html) ( type conversion ) a `String` to your `reader` object.

So to avoid that you can :

- Use an instance of your `reader` class. Here I should tell you that class names always start with a capital letter : `Reader` instead of `reader`. For more take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/writing-classes.html).

So for this case, you can do ( it's just an example, I don't see why you need this ) :

```
var reader:Reader;

// ...

function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
    loadedPage = loader.data;
    reader = new Reader(loadedPage);
}
```

- Use a `static` function, for example `read()`, like this :

```
public class Reader 
{
    // ...

    public static function read(loadedPage:String):void
    {
        trace(loadedPage);
    }
}
```

Then you can write :

```
function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
    loadedPage = loader.data;
    Reader.read(loadedPage);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: or make reader a top level function, which would allow the use of it as tried in the code in the question